# Does a Meta-Study contribute to the Body-of-Research and how?

Tags: publications, research-process, journals

The website [sciencealert](http://www.sciencealert.com/pregnancy-baby-brain-mumnesia-cognitive-function-meta-analysis) writes the following in one of their entries:

> The new meta-analysis of 20 studies updates the body of research regarding the phenomenon by including studies conducted more recently than 2007...

While I do see the value in a meta-analysis I am a bit unsure how it can **add** to the body of research since no new information/data is obtained.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on how you define the "body of research". If you see it purely as a collection of all raw data, then no, a a meta-analysis would not contribute to it. However, I would argue that most people use the term "body of knowledge" much more widely, to mean all research that has been conducted and all *knowledge* that has been generated and published in a field.

In order to be publishable, a meta-analysis should produce new knowledge (e.g., through new experiments or analyses, or by increasing our confidence in previously-published analyses through comparison over a larger sample size), and in that way contribute to the sum of all knowledge in the field, even if no new data points have been collected.

Comment: I was not sure whether the term body-of-research (and not knowledge) was intentionally used.

Answer (score 8):

A meta-analysis could be considered useful if it provides one or more of the following:

- **Synthesis:** A research domain may have tens or even hundreds of papers. A meta-analysis could provide a synthesized summary by providing classifications and catalogs.
- **New perspective:** Summarizing the existing studies from a new perspective could be very interesting. It could be from the technology side (for instance, how a new technology affects the previous results) or from the people side (for instance, how existing methods are seen by a manager vs by a student).
- **Research opportunities:** A meta-analysis may also explain not only how the research domain has evolved (in say, last 5 years) but also reveal gaps in the field.